# Is there a (command line) tool to calculate percentage change between two files of the same format full of numbers?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, diff, statistics

Is there a (command line) tool to calculate [percentage change](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-change-calculator.php) between two files of the same format full of numbers?

Example:

File A:

```
100 100
```

File B:

```
150 70
```

Invocation:

```
$ calc_perc_change A B
+50% -30%
```

Comment: I doubt, but this is very easily scriptable. The problem is you haven't provided your system.

Comment: It is rather simply done in a scripting language on linux/unix/mac. I recommend posting this on on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), tag it with [bash], [awk] and [perl]. Also, provide an attempt at coding it, even a simple one. If you file has more rows and columns, give a corresponding example. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On UNIX-like system, such as UNIX, Linux or macOS, use this Perl script:

```
perl -le '
( $old, $new ) =  @ARGV;
chomp ( @old = map { split "\t", $_ } do { local @ARGV = $old; <> } );
chomp ( @new = map { split "\t", $_ } do { local @ARGV = $new; <> } );
@pct_chg = ();
for $i ( 0 .. $#old ) {
    $pct_chg[$i] = 100 * ( $new[$i] - $old[$i] ) / abs( $old[$i] );
}
print join "\t", map { sprintf qq{%+d%}, $_ } @pct_chg;
' old.tsv new.tsv > pct_chg.tsv
```

I am assuming TAB-delimited input and output.

Example inputs:

```
echo '100\t100' > old.tsv
echo '150\t70' > new.tsv
```

Example output:

```
+50%    -30%
```

The Perl script uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`@ARGV` : Input file names.
`do { local @ARGV = $old; <> }` : slurp the input file into an array.
`map { split "\t", $_ }` : split the elements of the array (here, the array has only 1 element, the input line) into another array on TAB as a separator.
`chomp` : Remove input line separator, here newline.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)